# Python read relative dB from MP3 and FLAC without PyDub

Tags: python, audio, ffmpeg, decibel

I need to read a relative, to itself, average dB from a MP3 or FLAC. I can't use PyDub because it relies on FFMPEG/ AVCONV which I cannot install. A work around solution is acceptable eg: converting the MP3/ FLAC to wav before processing.

Comment: Why can't you install ffmpeg?

Comment: @llogan I could install it there is nothing physical stopping from installing it. However I do not want to install it as I'm working with something that has an extremely limited amount of space.